# Trying to install lucene for python. First need to install jcc. When building setup.py for jcc, I get the error ld: library not found for -ljava

Tags: python, lucene, jcc

Trying to install lucene for python. 
First need to install jcc. When building setup.py for jcc, I get the error ld: library not found for -ljava

```
Entire error can be found [here][1]: 

this is code
```

Comment: what is the meaning of "this is code"? did you forget to attach a hyperlink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for JCC](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/JCC/) states:

> JCC’s setup.py file needs to be edited before building JCC to specify the location of the Java Runtime Environment’s header files and libraries.

See also [building JCC](http://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/jcc/install.html#building-jcc).

On my OSX system, the discovered `JAVAHOME` and `JAVAFRAMEWORKS` are echoed when running install:

```
$ python setup.py install
found JAVAHOME = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home
found JAVAFRAMEWORKS = /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework
...
```

I tested with Python 2.7. Also, from the `jcc` source directory:

```
>>> from helpers2.darwin import JAVAHOME, JAVAFRAMEWORKS
found JAVAHOME = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home
found JAVAFRAMEWORKS = /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework
```

If your `JAVAHOME` isn't discovered, you can set the environment variable `JCC_JDK`. Example:

```
$ ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
jdk1.7.0_80.jdk     jdk1.8.0_25.jdk
jdk1.8.0_141.jdk    jdk1.8.0_91.jdk
$ JCC_JDK=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home python setup.py install
```

In this case it looks like `jdk1.7.0_80` is used for the compilation, but the first two line of output are:

```
found JAVAHOME = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home
found JAVAFRAMEWORKS = /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework
```

So that seems misleading, but appears to still work correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Would you know of anywhere I can get specifics on how to edit the setup.py? It does not seem self-explanatory and I am at a loss for finding anything online.

Comment: Looking at the [source for setup.py](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/pylucene/trunk/jcc/setup.py), it appears that the key is to get the JDK dictionary on line 68 set correctly for your platform. For example, if you are on Linux and JDK is not installed at `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`, you'll need to edit it accordingly.

Comment: I am working on Mac OS sierra. The key options in the dictionary are 'darwin', 'ipod', 'linux','sunos5','win32','mingw32', and 'freebsd7' 

I have been assuming that I am editing the darwin key, and I have been setting that to where my jdk-9.0.1.jdk directory is. 

There is also an environmental variable right underneath that dictionary called JCC_JDK that needs to be set. I have been setting that to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home. 

Is there anything wrong with how I am setting these variables?

Comment: I've updated my answer. It appears you don't need to edit `setup.py`, which is good because that's bad practice anyway. Instead you can just specify `JCC_JDK`, as noted in my revised answer. `JCC_JDK=Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home` should work, if that path exist. What are the first two lines of output, starting with `found JAVAHOME ...`? It's possible that JCC doesn't work with JRE 1.9. Can you revise your answer with the full output from `JCC_JDK=Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home python setup.py install`?

Comment: [Opened a ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PYLUCENE-40) in PyLucene issue tracker with some finding.

Comment: The actual error text is about 3000 characters to long. Do let me know if this is not sufficient. But I have the same values for JAVAHOME and JAVAFRAMEWORK and the JCC_JDK is set to the proper location 

ld: library not found for -ljava
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command '/usr/bin/clang++' failed with exit status 1

Comment: How about just an excerpt of a few lines around and including the error message? Please edit your post to include the message rather than posting as a comment, since the formatting is much better. Or you could post the entire log to pastebin and add a link.

Comment: i have added a pastebin link

Comment: Does the path `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib` exist? I installed JDK 9.0.4 and the equivalent of that path doesn't exist. However, it also fails with a different error: `OSError: warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.5`. This is pointing towards JDK 9 not being supported. If you can remove JDK 9 and install 1.8, that may be your quickest path to a solution. Otherwise, it might be necessary to figure out how to set all of the [environment variables](http://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/jcc/install.html#building-jcc).

Comment: Yes. I was able to install JCC after reverting to java 1.8. Thanks for your continued support.

Comment: Okay, I'm continuing to explore how to build against Java 1.8 when Java 9 is installed, discussing in [PYLUCENE-40](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PYLUCENE-40). I assume  you must have uninstalled Java 9, but that won't be a good solution for everyone. I'll update this answer when more information is found. If you are happy enough with the solution, could I ask you to please accept and upvote my answer? Thanks!

Comment: I attempted to upvote but it says i dont have enough reputation to upvote

Comment: Thanks for trying. It might be the case that you can only accept the answer, rather than upvoting it. I'm hoping my patch gets integrated to PyLucene so that the JDK can be specified using the variable `JCC_JDK`.